# Python Flask POST Method throwing Server overload and internal server error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, post, gunicorn

I am deploying my python Flask app in nginx server using gunicorn in Ubuntu. I am using mongodb. I have followed the steps from this https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a. Everything is working fine. I am able to get the response using GET method. But when I use POST method to insert into db it throws server overload error, internal server error. The code was working fine in development mode. This problem happened only when i moved the code to production.

Comment: Update your questions to post details about your server config, also what exception do you see in the logs

Comment: There is no exception in the logs. When I tested in postman the POST method returns server overload error.